# mpirun dosent work with openFoam (suddenly)

Tags: mpi

my mpirun on Ubuntu 20.04 dosent work anymore.

I used it a few weeks back and it works good and well. I just wanted to use it a few minutes ago and it doesent work.

I decompose the case first and then i use the

```
mpirun -np 4 interFoam -parallel
```

command.

Then this message appear.

```
kai@Kai-Desktop:~/OpenFOAM/kai-7/run/tutorials_of/multiphase/interFoam/laminar/damBreak_stl_II/damBreak$ mpirun -np 4 interFoam -parallel

It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)

It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)

It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)

It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "(null)" (-43) instead of "Success" (0)

*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[Kai-Desktop:3304] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[Kai-Desktop:3305] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[Kai-Desktop:3306] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[Kai-Desktop:3307] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.

mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[48186,1],0]
  Exit code:    1

 kai@Kai-Desktop:~/OpenFOAM/kai-7/run/tutorials_of/multiphase/interFoam/laminar/damBreak_stl_II/damBreak$
```

The Version of openMPI is this one:

```
kai@Kai-Desktop:~/Dokumente$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.0.3
```

I created a testfile *.c so far:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
           processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
 }
```

If i compile and execute it, this will be the answer:

```
kai@Kai-Desktop:~/Dokumente$ mpirun -np 4 ./hello_world -parallel
Hello world from processor Kai-Desktop, rank 0 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor Kai-Desktop, rank 1 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor Kai-Desktop, rank 2 out of 4 processors
Hello world from processor Kai-Desktop, rank 3 out of 4 processors
```

Does anyone know what to do, to get rid of this error ?
If you need further infos please write i will give it to you.
I dont aware changed anything on the system related to mpi. I do an update from 18.04 to 20.04, but i dont know if this leads to this error.

Best regards
Kai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my OF v7 to OF v8 and it works again..

still dont know why ...